# Go XML Unmarshalling attribute X of node N

Tags: xml, go

I would like to unmarshall the value of an attribute X of specific node N to a struct field. Something like this:

```
var data = `<A id="A_ID">
<B id="B_ID">Something</B>
</A>
`

type A struct {
    Id   string `xml:"id,attr"` // A_ID
    Name string `xml:"B.id,attr"` // B_ID
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/U6daYJWVUX

As far as I was able to [check](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal) this is not supported by Go. Am I correct, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you are not mentioning `B`. I'm guessing that you need to unmarshal its attr into `A.Name`? If so - you could change your A struct to something like this:

```
type A struct {
    Id string `xml:"id,attr"` // A_ID
    Name  struct {
        Id string `xml:"id,attr"` // B_ID
    } `xml:"B"`
}
```

Or maybe even better - define separate B struct:

```
type A struct {
    Id string `xml:"id,attr"` // A_ID
    Name  B `xml:"B"`
}

type B struct {
    Id string `xml:"id,attr"` // B_ID
}
```

Comment: I know it is possible to unmarshall this to several structs, but, as I've shown on the sample code on my question, I want to do that without having to replicate that hierarchy, otherwise, when you have multiple dependency levels it would be quite cumbersome to access the leaf nodes attributes as you would have to replicate the entire hierarchy with structs even if you don't really need them.

Comment: I see your point. [This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3633) might interest you.

Comment: that's it, especially https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3633#issuecomment-66067258 . let's hope they find some time to do it for the next release. thanks